# Gestures Prediction in Android

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gestures, prediction

I am trying to work on `Gestures` but the problem is I'm not able to understand some of the lines of code in the sample which is present in the developer's website. Can anyone just explain me the meaning of

```
prediction.score
prediction.size()
```

which is used everywhere in `Gestures`. In any sample app regarding Gestures I find these two, can anyone please let me know about it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you're talking about http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

It looks like this code sample has a typo, instead of

```
ArrayList<prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
```

it should be

```
ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
```

In this case `predictions.size()` indicates the number of gestures that matched the path the user drew on the screen.

`Prediction.score` is the level of confidence the framework has that a given Prediction is a match. The referenced page notes that confidence scores below 1.0 indicate poor matches.

Comment: i did it as you said but in my code i have prediction.size()>0 and when i want to print that in logcat its showing the value of prediction.size() as prediction.size()>037

Comment: can you pls tell me what does that mean?

Comment: It means there are 37 gestures that are a possible match for the one the user drew.

Comment: for every gesture its showing the same count. does that mean that for every gesture that the user drew there are 37 possible matches. How can that count be stable for every gesture?

Comment: Possibly, perhaps it is giving a confidence score for all gestures in the library.